Does $g^{ij}\Gamma_{ij}^k=0$?
Let $(M,g)$ be a Riemannian manifold, and $\nabla$ the Levi-Civita connection. In local coordinates, the Levi-Civita connection is essentially $d+\Gamma_{ij}^k$, where $\Gamma_{ij}^k$ are the Chrstophell Symbols.
I have recently come across the expression $\langle dx^i,dx^j\rangle\Gamma_{ij}^k$, and my life would be infinitely easier if this term were zero, as it would imply two things which both appear to be a formal adjoint, are actually the same thing.
In local coordinates we have that:
\begin{align}
g^{ij}\Gamma_{ij}^k=\frac{1}{2}g^{ij}g^{kl}\left(\partial_i g_{jl}+\partial_j g_{il}-\partial_lg_{ij}\right )
\end{align}
I believe we can make the following identifications:
\begin{align}
g^{ij}\partial_ig_{jl}=&-g_{jl}\partial_ig^{ij}\\
g^{ij}\partial_jg_{il}=&-g_{il}\partial_jg^{ij}\\
-g^{ij}\partial_lg_{ij}=&g_{ij}\partial_lg^{ij}
\end{align}
If we apply $g^{kl}$ to each term, we get:
\begin{align}
-\delta^i_l\partial_ig^{ij}\qquad \text{and}\qquad -\delta^j_l\partial_jg^{ij}\qquad \text{and} \qquad g^{kl}g_{ij}\partial_lg^{ij}
\end{align}
but I am not sure how to proceed. Perhaps this is not true thought and I have made a mistake elsewhere though.

This identity is wrong. We know that the Euclidean metric
in polar coordinates is $ds^2=dr^2+r^2\,d\theta^2$ and has non-zero Christoffel symbols
$$
\Gamma^r_{\theta\theta}=-r\,,\quad \Gamma^\theta_{r\theta}=\Gamma^\theta_{\theta r}=\frac{1}{r}\,.
$$
Thus, with $k=r\,,$
$$
g^{ij}\,\Gamma^r_{ij}=-\frac 1r\,.
$$

Thank you! should have just calculated something explicitly. Now I must hunt for my mistake...

You are welcome. If you browse my MSE answers you will mostly see just that example :)

The Christoffel symbols of $g$ with respect to coordinates $(x^1, \dots, x^n)$ satisfy $$ g^{ij}\Gamma^k_{ij} = 0 $$ if and only if each coordinate function $x^k$ is harmonic, i.e., $$\Delta_g x^k = 0. $$ This is easy to verify by simply writing $\Delta f$ in local coordinates.
Local harmonic coordinates always exist. The Lorentzian version was used, I believe, by Choquet-Bruhat. The Riemannian version was, I believe, first used by DeTurck and Kazdan. Estimates for the size of the neighborhood on which these coordinates exist were proved by Greene and Wu, Stefan Peters, and Mike Anderson.
